# REGEX Expression to exclude toll-free numbers

Tags: java, regex

I have this regex expression written that should extract toll-free  numbers but when there is a number like 1-800-343-2432 (when there is a 1 before the 800 stuff) it doesn't work

```
(?!(\$|#|800|855|866|877|888))\(?[\\s.-]*([0-9]{3})?[\\s.-]*\)?[\\s.-]*[0-9]{3}[\\s.-]*[0-9]{4}
```

how can i modify this expression to not take numbers like 1-866-343-1232 too ?!

Comment: Can you clarify the question please? What do you want to extract, exactly? Please show a sample input and output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without checking your full regex you can use this regex to block `1-888`:

```
(?!(?:1-)?(\\$|#|800|855|866|877|888))\(?[\\s.-]*([0-9]{3})?[\\s.-]*\)?[\\s.-]*[0-9]{3}[\\s.-]*[0-9]{4}
```

Comment: when testing it gave me this error:
'Multiple markers at this line
 - Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r 
  \" \' \\ )
 - Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r 
  \" \' \\ )' 

for this portion: 
" (?!(?:1-)?(\$ "

Comment: Your regex in question seemed faulty. Try updated regex.

Comment: @anubhava Just to make a mention, you are making the 1 optional, however you have put this in a non-capturing group as well as making it a negative lookahead, meaning the match on 1- is discarded.

Comment: Yes that is what intended by OP to avoid matching `1-800` numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Prepend `(1-)?` to your regex. This will work for optional `1-`.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying your regular expression:

```
(\+)?(1-)?\(?(\\$|#|800|855|866|877|888)\)?[\\s.-]*([0-9]{3})?[\\s.-]*\)?[\\s.-]*[0-9]{3}[\\s.-]*[0-9]{4}
```

The key differences here are the following:

`(\+)?` :: A lazy quantifier `?' matches a + character if it takes place prior to the 1. Many numbers display like +1-800-343-2432

`(1-)?` :: Matches a 1 followed by a - character. The `?` is a lazy quantifier that matches the `1-` if it exists.

And I also added `\(?` and `\)?` which allow you to match on numbers that present in the format +1-(800)-343-2432